# Cant get a text box state to refresh with user input, keeps going to default state despite using setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React file which displays a list of city data as a component. there is an input textbox above it which needs to accept user input. i am using state to display an initial string in the textbox, but i cannot get onChange to successfully use a function to setState. troubleshooting it with console.log i can see that when i attempt to change the state the function i am pointing to with onChange does work and changes one letter, but then the state snaps back to its default value. the problem seems to be with setState not saving the change and reverting back to the initial state after any changes are made. the text box content appears to not change at all, thought console.log shows a one letter change but then reverts back to the original state.

how do i update state? i want the user to be able to punch a number in and then compare it with the list.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Table from './Table';
import cities from './Cities';


class App extends Component {

state = {
    userInput: "Your City Population"
}


popChanger = (event) => {
    this.setState( {userInput: event.target.value} );
    //console.log(event.target.value);
}

yourCity = (
    <div>
        <input 
            type='text' 
            onChange={this.popChanger}
            value={this.state.userInput}
            />
    </div>
)


render() {



    return (

        <div className = "App">
            {this.yourCity}
            <Table characterData = {cities} />
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default App;
```

Comment: you have to call the function `this.yourCity()`

Comment: its not a function but i gave you a +1 because you gave me an idea. the variable (Block of JSX) was outside of the render method. i thought i'd be efficient by making a variable and then calling the JSX block inside render/return. the problem is that it wasn't being updated outside of the render method. 

i just erased the yourCity variable (block of JSX ) from outside the render method and wrote that code withing the JSX of the return method in the render method. 

works now!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState()` is saving your changes, just not in the right place,

`popChanger()` is an arrow function and updates the state of the `App` component, 
`yourCity` has it's own `this` so it doesn't know about the `App` state.

you can either cahnge `yourCity` to an arrow function that returns the html you want like

```
class TodoApp extends React.Component {

    state = {
        a: ''
    };

    YourCity = () => (
        <div>    
          <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.a} />
        </div>
    }


    handleChange = e => this.setState({a : e.target.value})

    render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <this.YourCity />

          </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Or, create `yourCity` component outside and pass the `handleChange` as a prop :

```
const YourCity = props => (
        <div>    
          <input type="text" onChange={props.handleChange} value={props.value} />
        </div>
    )

class TodoApp extends React.Component {

    state = {
        a: ''
    };


    handleChange = e => this.setState({a : e.target.value})

    render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <YourCity handleChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.a}/>

      </div>
    )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Answer (score 1):

The state is updating but you can't see that because `this.yourCity` doesn't re-render

```
popChanger = (event) => {

    this.setState( {userInput: event.target.value} );
    console.log(event.target.value);
}

yourCity(){
  return <div>
        <input 
            type='text' 
            onChange={this.popChanger}
            value={this.state.userInput}
            />
    </div>
}


render() {



    return (

        <div className = "App">
            {this.yourCity()}

        </div>
    );
}
}
```